# Pulling image from remote source Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, image, getelementsbytagname, domparser

I am trying to pull the first image I can get from a URL and display it in a div.

I can successfully pull things such as title and headers from the URL but images will not work.

```
var html = httpRequest.responseText;
var DOMparser = new DOMParser();                   
var xmlDocument = parser.parseFromString (html, "text/xml"); 

title = xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName('title');
image = xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName('img');
```

When I view `title[0].innerHTML` I can get the title. However, doing the same for image, it always comes up as undefined. Even when i do image.src

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`<img />` does not have inner HTML, you have to access its attributes.

Answer (score 0):

As @QBernard says, the image element does not have any inner html. Try accessing it's src property using the following code;

```
var imageUrl = image[0].getAttribute('src');
```

Comment: Then my guess is your code isn't pulling through any img elements at all. Have you tried looping through your image array or logging it to console to see if anything is stored in it?

Comment: yes and its empty :/ thanks for helping i appreciate it

Comment: Ah, that explains it. No worries, as to why it's not coming up with images - I dunno. I'd have to see your whole script.